# RxJava Observable Timeout not working at times

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

The below is my code snippet, and sometimes the `Observable` does not time out,

```
 Observable<A> AObservable = Observable.fromCallable(() ->
        //External Service Call
).timeout(800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .onErrorReturn(throwable -> {
            LOGGER.warn(format("Server did not respond within %s ms for id=%s", 800, id));
            return null;
        });

Observable<B> BObservable = Observable.fromCallable(() ->
        //External Service Call
).timeout(800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .onErrorReturn( throwable -> {
            LOGGER.warn(format("Service did not respond within %s ms for id=%s", 800, Id));
            return null;
        });

// Build Default response
Observable<C> CObservable = Observable.fromCallable(() ->
        // Build Default one
).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());


return Observable.zip(AObservable, BObservable,CObservable,
        (AResponse, BResponse, CResponse) -> {

    // Handle response and combine them

}).toBlocking().first();
```

It appears to me that at times the if the service takes more than `800ms` the timeout does not happen. Do I miss any attribute here please advise.

Comment: Works for me: https://gist.github.com/akarnokd/5d2fd0368c9bdb72671d0808274203dc

Comment: @akarnokd Thanks for looking into this and it works for me too but at times it looks like the timeout is not happening. I will look into the other aspects of this problem and post here if the original issue is not with `timeout`.

Comment: If you are using RxJava2, then attempting to push `null` into the observer chain will cause an exception. If you have a custom hook for catching nested exceptions, then something may get eaten.